# HTTP Put request works using Sun Jersey Client 1.19, but same request is not using SoapUI or Postman

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a server that provides `REST` webservice to edit users data on the server's DB, the company that developed the webservice provided a sample client that uses `com.sun.jersey.api.client`, below is the sample code:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.api.representation.Form;
import java.util.Properties;

public class entryClass {

    private static Client client;
    private static ClientConfig config;
    private static String truststoreFileName = "C:\\trust.jks";
    private static String truststorePassword = "123456";
    private static String username = "mahmoud";
    private static String password = "Avaya123$";
    private static String uri = "https://avaya-smgr01.atcom.ae/web/mgmtwebservice";
    private final static String entityType = "user";
    private final static String entityXmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delta:deltaUserList xmlns:delta=\"http://xml.avaya.com/schema/deltaImport\" xmlns:ns3=\"http://xml.avaya.com/schema/import_sessionmanager\" xmlns:ns4=\"http://xml.avaya.com/schema/import_csm_b5800\" xmlns:ns5=\"http://xml.avaya.com/schema/import_csm_mm\" xmlns:ns6=\"http://xml.avaya.com/schema/import_csm_cm\" xmlns:ns7=\"http://xml.avaya.com/schema/import_csm_agent\" xmlns:ns8=\"http://xml.avaya.com/schema/import\" xmlns:tns=\"http://xml.avaya.com/schema/import\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://xml.avaya.com/schema/deltaImport userdeltaimport.xsd\"><delta:userDelta><loginName>ghaith@atcom.ae</loginName><commProfileSet><commProfileSetName>Primary</commProfileSetName><isPrimary>true</isPrimary><commProfileList><commProfile xmlns:ns9=\"http://xml.avaya.com/schema/import_csm_cm\" xsi:type=\"ns9:xmlStationProfile\"><commProfileType>CM</commProfileType><ns9:cmName>AVAYA-CM</ns9:cmName><ns9:useExistingExtension>true</ns9:useExistingExtension><ns9:extension>727</ns9:extension><ns9:cor>55</ns9:cor></commProfile></commProfileList></commProfileSet></delta:userDelta></delta:deltaUserList>";
    private final static String updateType = "merge";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", truststoreFileName);
        properties.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", truststorePassword);
        config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        client = Client.create(config);
        client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username, password));
        final Form form = new Form();
        form.add("entityType", entityType);
        form.add("entityXMLData", entityXmlData);
        form.add("updateMode", updateType);
        client.resource(uri).put(String.class, form);
    }
}
```

Running the above code gives the following output:

```
1 * Client out-bound request
1 > PUT https://avaya-smgr01.atcom.ae/web/mgmtwebservice
1 > Authorization: Basic bWFobW91ZDpBdmF5YTEyMyQ=
updateMode=merge&entityType=user&entityXMLData=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%3Cdelta%3AdeltaUserList+xmlns%3Adelta%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fxml.avaya.com%2Fschema%2FdeltaImport%22+xmlns%3Ans3%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fxml.avaya.com%2Fschema%2Fimport_sessionmanager%22+xmlns%3Ans4%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fxml.avaya.com%2Fschema%2Fimport_csm_b5800%22+xmlns%3Ans5%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fxml.avaya.com%2Fschema%2Fimport_csm_mm%22+xmlns%3Ans6%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fxml.avaya.com%2Fschema%2Fimport_csm_cm%22+xmlns%3Ans7%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fxml.avaya.com%2Fschema%2Fimport_csm_agent%22+xmlns%3Ans8%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fxml.avaya.com%2Fschema%2Fimport%22+xmlns%3Atns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fxml.avaya.com%2Fschema%2Fimport%22+xmlns%3Axsi%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance%22+xsi%3AschemaLocation%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fxml.avaya.com%2Fschema%2FdeltaImport+userdeltaimport.xsd%22%3E%3Cdelta%3AuserDelta%3E%3CloginName%3Eghaith%40atcom.ae%3C%2FloginName%3E%3CcommProfileSet%3E%3CcommProfileSetName%3EPrimary%3C%2FcommProfileSetName%3E%3CisPrimary%3Etrue%3C%2FisPrimary%3E%3CcommProfileList%3E%3CcommProfile+xmlns%3Ans9%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fxml.avaya.com%2Fschema%2Fimport_csm_cm%22+xsi%3Atype%3D%22ns9%3AxmlStationProfile%22%3E%3CcommProfileType%3ECM%3C%2FcommProfileType%3E%3Cns9%3AcmName%3EAVAYA-CM%3C%2Fns9%3AcmName%3E%3Cns9%3AuseExistingExtension%3Etrue%3C%2Fns9%3AuseExistingExtension%3E%3Cns9%3Aextension%3E727%3C%2Fns9%3Aextension%3E%3Cns9%3Acor%3E55%3C%2Fns9%3Acor%3E%3C%2FcommProfile%3E%3C%2FcommProfileList%3E%3C%2FcommProfileSet%3E%3C%2Fdelta%3AuserDelta%3E%3C%2Fdelta%3AdeltaUserList%3E
1 * Client in-bound response
1 < 200
1 < Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
1 < Connection: keep-alive
1 < Set-Cookie: avaya-smgr01.atcom.ae=1gFtZiuD53fAwbKWNBCTjBl2PWFuZ4_FwiiE0Oo535NMf70FsGdJp-2pC2kUcn8C*AAJTSQACMDE.*; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
1 < Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DmYwtUKB18qGIWfAlEmQcK5D1-NNgPmOHiO95SmJ.avaya-smgr01; path=/web; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
1 < Pragma: no-cache
1 < Expires: 0
1 < Content-Length: 104
1 < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
1 < Date: Sat, 28 Dec 2019 08:38:19 GMT
1 < Content-Type: application/xml
1 < 
Operation=Update User, LoginId: mahmoud, Action: Update, merge, Object=ghaith@atcom.ae, Status: Success
```

I'm trying to reproduce the same request on SoapUI or Postman, but the server keeps giving forbidden 403.

what i understand from the code is:

- request requires Basic HTTP Authentication
- request is sent over HTTPS so there must be a trust store that
  contains the service CA
- Jersey will encode the request to URL encoded request and use the
  values as request parameters in the URI like so: `https://avaya-smgr01.atcom.ae/web/mgmtwebservice?updateMode=merge&entityType=user&entityXMLData=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%22.......%3E`

I've tried calling the URL with the encoded format using postman and soapui and set up basic HTTP authentication and disabled URL formatting on both, but still the server is responding with forbidden 403. Also tried to to let SoapUI and Postman to encode the request but still gives the same error

[image: Postman request]
[image: Postman Basic Auth settings]
Can someone tell me what am I missing ?

Comment: What the code does us put the data into the body of the request in the form of application/x-www-form-urlencoded data type. This is what the `Form` class is used for. You are trying to put the data in the query string. That actual format of data between form-urlencoded and query params are actually exactly the same. It's just one goes in the body and one goes in the URL. So you need to change the [Body] tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTTP PUT request should have the values specified in the body not in the URL's query parameters.